# TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' | total_number_messages += result["verify_counter"]

Tags: python, django

```
print("* Parsing users email in parallel..") 
pool = Pool(processes=NUM_PROCESSES)
for result in pool.imap_unordered(worker, usernames, chunksize = 2): 
    total_number_messages += result["verify_counter"] 
    total_number_messages_imported += result["num_imported"] 
    total_number_duplicates += result["duplicate_counter"] 
    address_book[result["current_user_email"]] = result["username"] 
    combined_msg_senders.append({
                                "counter": result["counter"],
                                "address": result["current_user_email"],
                                "username": result["username"]
                                })
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

please help me with this error getting for above, getting error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "metadata.py", line 539, in <module>
    main()
  File "metadata.py", line 511, in main
    total_number_messages += result["verify_counter"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

that code you can check at 
http://brage.bibsys.no/xmlui/handle/11250/198551

Comment: You need to post any relevant code *here*. People will not download and read a whole thesis just to see where your code might be broken.

Comment: Looking at pages 123 - 126 you'll see the working can end up returning `None` if there is an exception. It'll also return a *tuple* in certain cases.

Answer (score 2):

`result` is set to `None`, so `result[...]` fails.

`result` is `None` if `worker()` returned `None`. Make sure your workers *always* return a result, or explicitly test for `result is not None` first.